# Horizontal timeline for Wordpress posts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, customization, timeline, posts

I am busy creating a blog for myself and need to make a horizontal timeline, but I am not sure about how to achieve this.

I have spent the better part of my evening googling and found this timeline http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/ but it's a lot more extensive than I need.

Basically I am wanting to make something pretty much like this but with out the content slider or the JSON content, just a timeline that shows the posts with their titles maybe a thumbnail and of course places the correctly on the time line corresponding to the date they were created.

Any ideas how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Modify the plugin you linked in your post.

Comment: I have rethought what I need to do in oder to get the data for the timeline. Since I will be using wordpress I can just echo the posts into a list within <div id="timeline"> which will give me the data. So now my problem is with how do I line up my posts with a timeline like the example above?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but the answer can be helpful to others, Post Timeline offer horizontal and vertical timeline, you can download it for WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-timeline/

[Demos of the Timeline](https://posttimeline.com/timeline-templates/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but i really want to share a solution i have found.

Using WordPress, [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)(ACF) and [TIMELINE JS](https://timeline.knightlab.com/)(TL) together.

**I really like timeline js and especially their mobil friendly look is perfect! Check it out.**

I wanted to be able to make a user for my school so that basically everyone could use WordPress user friendly design and **create new events** for the TL frontend view.

> Not everyone is comfortable with excel and it is not the best to work in, with this kind of data, i would say.

To be able to do this, i wrote some code that takes all the posts of the WordPress installation and export them to a json format file that TL can read as events, every time you update or create a new post.

*You can read more about the json structure [here](https://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/json-format.html)*

#### 1. step

Create two date fields with ACF - one for start date and one for end date - and make the return format as Ymd
[image]

Set them to show for posts.

#### 2. - export the data

After that this code will export the posts data to a file in your filestructure: 
*`startdato` and `slutdato` are the two ACF fields start and end date*

```
function export_posts_in_json (){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );


    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $text = new stdClass();
    $text->headline = "Det Kongelige Danske Kunstakademi";
    $text->text = "Som har været en del igennem";
    $timelineObj = new stdClass();
    $timelineObj->title = "media";
    $timelineObj->title = $text;

    $eventArray = array();

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      $obj = new stdClass();

      if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $media = new stdClass();
        $media->url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); 
        $media->thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
        $media->caption = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
        $obj->media = $media;
      }

      $text = new stdClass();
      $text->headline = get_the_title();
      $text->text = get_the_content();

      $obj->text = $text;

      $startDate = new stdClass();
      $dateObject = new DateTime( get_field('startdato', get_the_ID() ) ); 
      $startDate->year = $dateObject->format('Y');
      $startDate->month = $dateObject->format('m');
      $startDate->day = $dateObject->format('d');

      $obj->start_date = $startDate;

      if( get_field('slutdato', get_the_ID() ) ) {  // Hvis der er en slutdato
        $endDate = new stdClass();
        $dateObject = new DateTime( get_field('slutdato', get_the_ID() ) ); 
        $endDate->year = $dateObject->format('Y');
        $endDate->month = $dateObject->format('m');
        $endDate->day = $dateObject->format('d');

        $obj->end_date = $endDate;
      }
      if( get_the_category() ) { // Can only take one!
        $category = new stdClass();
        $obj->group = get_the_category()[0]->name;
      }

      $eventArray[] = $obj; 

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    $timelineObj->events = $eventArray;

    $data = json_encode($timelineObj);
    $folder = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/it-timeline/';
    $file_name = 'timeline-data.json';
    $succes = file_put_contents( $folder.$file_name , $data );

}
```

This will save the data and be readable for TL (as i said).

#### 3. implement the libraries

Then add the TL javascript and CSS and call the file from one of your `.php`files:

```
<link title="timeline-styles" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css">
<script src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js"></script>

<div id='timeline-embed' style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
      hash_bookmark: true 
  }

  var json_url = "wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/it-timeline/timeline-data.json"

  $.getJSON( json_url, function( data ) {
      timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', data, options);
      console.log(data);
  } );
</script>
```

#### Voila!

Now you have the possibility to share a user-login with a friend or colleague that maybe isn't the best in Excel, or just want the functionality of WordPress. Or as in my case, if you want to develop a timeline with a lot of different peoples knowledge, **you can work collectively** on a project in a user friendly flow - not in excel.

**Hope this will help someone**

It works for me.